# Problema con Combobox en Frame "scrollable", el evento de scroll pasa al padre

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Estoy realizando una aplicación de escritorio con Tkinter y Python. He insertado un control desplegable `ttk.Combobox` para varias opciones pero tengo un problema. El *combobox* está dentro de un *frame* con barra de *scroll* y cuando bajo la ruleta del ratón el cuadro del *combobox* se baja junto con todo el *frame*, es algo muy raro. ¿Alguien sabe solucionar esto?.

Este es mi código, la clase `VerticalScrolledFrame` está descargada de GitHub:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='green',
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = tk.Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=tk.NW)
        def _on_mousewheel(event):
            canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
        self.interior.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):


        super().__init__(main_window)


        main_window.geometry("400x400")

        frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(main_window)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        optionList = ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5','option6','option7','option8',]
        combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame.interior, state="readonly", height=4, values=optionList)
        combobox.pack(side='top')

        for i in range(20):
            tk.Button(frame.interior, text= 'Button'+str(i)).pack()


main_window = tk.Tk()
app = Application(main_window)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: provee un [mcve] si deseas ayuda ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que **se está usando `bind_all` para enlazar los eventos de scroll con la callback**. `bind_all` realiza el enlace a nivel de la aplicación, por lo que **todos los eventos** generados por la rueda del ratón en la aplicación terminan llamando a la **callback `_on_mousewheel` de la última instancia de la clase `VerticalScrolledFrame`**. Lo anterior ocasiona que al llevar a cabo un scroll en el `Combobox`, no solo se ejecuta su propia callback, también la asociada a nivel de app por `bind_all`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se soluciona usando `bind` que realiza el enlace del evento con la callback a nivel de widget (instancia) y no a nivel de toda la app como hace `bind_all`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)   

        self._vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self._vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='green',
                                 yscrollcommand=self._vscrollbar.set)
        self._canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self._vscrollbar.config(command=self._canvas.yview)

        self._canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self._canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self._inner_frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._inner_id = self._canvas.create_window(0, 0,
                                                    window=self._inner_frame,
                                                    anchor=tk.NW
                                                   )
        self._inner_frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel) 
        self._inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_inner)                
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)

    @property
    def container(self):
        return self._inner_frame

    def _configure_canvas(self, event):
        width = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self._canvas.winfo_width())
        height = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqheight(), self._canvas.winfo_height())
        self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._inner_id, width=width, height=height)

    def _configure_inner(self, event):
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self._canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
        return "break"


class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.geometry("400x400")
        frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(main_window)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        optionList = ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5','option6','option7','option8',]
        combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame.container, name="combo",  state="readonly",
                                height=4, values=optionList
                                )
        combobox.pack(side='top')

        for i in range(20):
            btn = tk.Button(frame.container, text= 'Button' + str(i))
            btn.pack()
            # Habilitamos el scroll en los botones
            btn.bind("<MouseWheel>", frame.on_mousewheel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(main_window)
    app.mainloop()
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** en Linux con X11 el evento `"<MouseWheel>"` no es el apropiado para capturar el scroll de la rueda del ratón, en su lugar se deben capturar los eventos `"<Button-4>"` (subir) y `"<Button-5>"` (bajar):
>
> ```
> self._inner_frame.bind("<Button-4>", self.on_mousewheel) 
> self._inner_frame.bind("<Button-5>", self.on_mousewheel) 
>
> def on_mousewheel(self, event):
>     if event.num == 4:
>         print(4)
>         self._canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")
>     elif event.num == 5:
>         print(5)
>         self._canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")
> ```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias FJSevilla. Verás, soy relativamente nuevo en python y todavia me cuesta un poco, tengo un problema con la clase VerticalScrolledFrame. Yo entiendo que esa clase me proporciona un FRAME con barra de scroll vertical, mi problema viene cuando utilizo mas de una vez la clase. Tengo varias pestañas en un tk.Notebook y quiero tener mas de un frame con scroll, el problema es que el evento de la rueda del raton unicamente funciona en uno. Creo que lo mas correcto es crear otro hilo con otra pregunta, corregidme si me equivoco. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Hola Alfredo, tienes toda la razón, fue error mio al no prestar la suficiente atención al código de la clase `VerticalScrolledFrame`  que proveías y pasar por alto que el enlace del evento se estaba realizando incorrectamente, el problema no se observa con una sola instancia del widget. He modificado esto en la clase junto a otros detalles (por ejemplo, ahora el frame interior se expande en ambas direcciones si la ventana lo hace) y he actualizado la explicación. Todo debe ir bien ahora sin necesidad tampoco del método anterior, no obstante si encuentras algún bug comenta.

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, lo revisaré. No sabía que había que aceptar las respuestas.

Comment: De nada Alfredo . He visto que al final creaste otra pregunta, en realidad teniendo en cuenta mi despiste :( ambos problemas están directamente relacionados.  Te dejo el código de la otra pregunta corregida en base a lo explicado aquí en Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/CarefreeWeightyPolygons por si  te surge alguna duda,  si el problema queda solucionado considera eliminar la otra pregunta, creo que es mejor que marcarla como duplicado.  Un saludo.

Comment: Perdona que sea tan pesado FJSevilla, funciona a la perfeccion, lo unico que cuando el cursor esta encima de los botones en este ejemplo, no se ejecuta el evento de scroll. Esto es un problema para mi porque en mi aplicacion original dentro del frame.container tengo en una pestaña varios graficos, y en otra varios LabelFrame con controles de usuario etc... Entonces el scroll solo se ejecuta cuando el cursor esta en una zona en concreto (la zona de Frame.container). Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto? Porque con la "version" anterior esto no pasaba. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Si quieres que el scroll tenga lugar en algún widget hijo que no propague el evento solo tienes que enlazar el evento en ese widget al método `on_mousewheel` de su  frame padre (instancia de `VerticalScrolledFrame`). He editado el ejemplo añadiendo esto. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!